# how to implement saving?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to make the button save the path to its application. That is, I bind, say, a shortcut to a button, everything works, but if I restart, everything needs to be done again. Please tell me how to implement saving?

my code:

```
import tkinter.filedialog as tfd
import tkinter as tk
import os


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Мой Открыватель")
window.geometry("600x400")
window.resizable(False, False)

file_name = ""


def open():
    global file_name
    if file_name == "":
        file_name = tfd.askopenfilename()
        os.startfile(file_name)
    else:
        os.startfile(file_name)
    if btn1["text"] == "":
        btn1["text"] = file_name


btn1 =  tk.Button(window, text="", command=open)
btn1.place(x = 20, y = 25)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please be more clear on what you mean by saving the path to its application. Do you mean storing the application associated with the file? Or using the application to save the file? What are you trying to save? What needs to be done again? Including detailed information like this in your question will help us better answer your question. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info on asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save data in many different ways. Three such ways are:

1. Use a database, for example sqlite to store your data. Fetch your data when the program starts and populate the required fields. -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
2. Serialize your data with the use of pickle -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html (Please note, pickle is not secure)
3. Use a .txt, .csv or other types of files. Write your data to the file, then when your program starts, load the data from the file.